# best way to keep token for login section in flutter

Tags: flutter

I wrote the registry system with http library in flutter and its database is mysql

I now want to write it login but I do not know what is the best way

For example, in React, we use Local Storage for storage data

but I do not know what is the best way to store token in the flutter

Comment: you can try using local storage like shared preference https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0):

Before use this add shared_preferences from https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Try this solution to store your token to local preference.

Save the data in shared-preference

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String token = '54dsfdsfsdfsdf5ad4f5sdafsd25f45';
pref.setString('token', token);
```

Retrive data from shared-preference

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String token = pref.getString('token')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i use SharedPreferences for onboarding intro , i can use again that for login? | and you have any reference for sharedPreference that use of that for login?

Comment: You can save this token for first time and after that whenever you come first screen just check this token is exist or not. and based on the result you can navigate whatever screen you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Chirag,
[shared_preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) is a nice dependency to store data like user preferences.
But to store auth token or any other token I would prefer to use [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) so the token is encrypted and secured (it support all platforms)

Comment: are you have example for this dependency that used for login with API?

Comment: @Hossein What have you problem with ? The documentation of the package describe all the instructions to create a secure storage, add a token (or any information) in the storage and delete any token (or any information) from the secure storage.

Comment: i should see a video or example of that to learn using that , in youtube i can't find anything about this

Comment: https://github.com/JohannesMilke/secure_storage_example @Hossein
You can find public code using this dependency by taping the keywords on github.
https://github.com/search?q=flutter_secure_storage